# Problem in withdraw() function in Auction contract, !payable is used still its able to refund the amount of the lower bidders when we click withdraw

Tags: solidity, ether, javascript, addresses, payable

In Withdraw Function, !payable condition is given, but payable condition not given, still when we click withdraw, then we will get our money back if we dont have the highest bid

````
pragma solidity ^0.8.4;
contract SimpleAuction {

// Parameters of the auction. Times are either
// absolute unix timestamps (seconds since 1970-01-01)
// or time periods in seconds.

address payable public beneficiary;
uint public auctionEndTime;

// Current state of the auction.

address public highestBidder;
uint public highestBid;

// Allowed withdrawals of previous bids

mapping(address => uint) pendingReturns;

// Set to true at the end, disallows any change.
// By default initialized to `false`.

bool ended;

// Events that will be emitted on changes.

event HighestBidIncreased(address bidder, uint amount);
event AuctionEnded(address winner, uint amount);

// Errors that describe failures.
// The triple-slash comments are so-called natspec
// comments. They will be shown when the user
// is asked to confirm a transaction or
// when an error is displayed.
/// The auction has already ended.

error AuctionAlreadyEnded();

/// There is already a higher or equal bid.

error BidNotHighEnough(uint highestBid);

/// The auction has not ended yet.

error AuctionNotYetEnded();

/// The function auctionEnd has already been called.

error AuctionEndAlreadyCalled();

/// Create a simple auction with `biddingTime`
/// seconds bidding time on behalf of the
/// beneficiary address `beneficiaryAddress`.

constructor(
uint biddingTime,
address payable beneficiaryAddress
) {
beneficiary = beneficiaryAddress;
auctionEndTime = block.timestamp + biddingTime;
}

/// Bid on the auction with the value sent
/// together with this transaction.
/// The value will only be refunded if the
/// auction is not won.

function bid() external payable {

// No arguments are necessary, all
// information is already part of
// the transaction. The keyword payable
// is required for the function to
// be able to receive Ether.
// Revert the call if the bidding
// period is over.

if (block.timestamp > auctionEndTime)
revert AuctionAlreadyEnded();

// If the bid is not higher, send the
// money back (the revert statement
// will revert all changes in this
// function execution including
// it having received the money).

if (msg.value <= highestBid)
revert BidNotHighEnough(highestBid);
if (highestBid != 0) {

// Sending back the money by simply using
// highestBidder.send(highestBid) is a security risk
// because it could execute an untrusted contract.
// It is always safer to let the recipients
// withdraw their money themselves.

pendingReturns[highestBidder] += highestBid;
}
highestBidder = msg.sender;
highestBid = msg.value;
emit HighestBidIncreased(msg.sender, msg.value);
}

/// Withdraw a bid that was overbid.

function withdraw() external returns (bool) {
uint amount = pendingReturns[msg.sender];
if (amount > 0) {

// It is important to set this to zero because the recipient
// can call this function again as part of the receiving call
// before `send` returns.
pendingReturns[msg.sender] = 0;
// msg.sender is not of type `address payable` and must be
// explicitly converted using `payable(msg.sender)` in order
// use the member function `send()`.

if (!payable(msg.sender).send(amount)) {

// No need to call throw here, just reset the amount owing

pendingReturns[msg.sender] = amount;
return false;
}
}
return true;
} ```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll suggest you change the logic of your withdraw function, if the `send` fails the transaction will be reverted.

So no need to check anything.

```
function withdraw() external returns (bool) {
    uint amount = pendingReturns[msg.sender];
    if (amount > 0) {
        pendingReturns[msg.sender] = 0;
        payable(msg.sender).send(amount);
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Brother, sorry for very late reply, It worked as expected, I forgot to rply that time. Much thanks for the help !!